# KVO: Should I explicitly remove an object as an observer?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a table view controller whose cells display the content of a different object. Since the content of these objects can be updated, I use KVO to be notified of changes in order to update the table cell view.

Now [on this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-BAJEAIEE) Apple notes that:

> The key-value observing `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method
>   does not retain the observing object or the observed objects. You need
>   to review your application’s requirements and manage retain and
>   release for the observing, and observed, objects.

Could someone tell me what would happen if the view controller is destroyed and I haven't called `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` on each of the observed objects? Will this cause a bad access or will the framework not send the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a bad access error. Better to remove your controller from observers.